# Where is docusign templateid?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use the docusign api. Where can I get the templateid? I created a template on the demo site but I can't find the templateid. Can I make an api call to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can make an API call to retrieve a list of the templates in your account, see the [Get List of Templates](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20List%20of%20Templates.htm) call.  Besides that, the other two quick ways of getting the template ID of a given template are:

1. Navigate to a given template in your account and copy the id from the URL.
2. Switch back to the CLASSIC UI in the DocuSign Web Application, then go to the first page of template configuration and the Template ID will be listed.

For #1, the URL will be in the form:  `https://appdemo.docusign.com/templates/details/a5d247e4-03e8-4318-b1f6-27bb3c0b0f27`.  Here `a5d247e4-03e8-4318-b1f6-27bb3c0b0f27` is the template ID.

Comment: Thanks. If you don't know what you are looking for, grabbing it from the url is not obvious. It would be nice to label it on the page.